# PrivateMemorySize64 not decreasing if Process.GetCurrentProcess() handle held

Tags: c#, windows, memory

In the program below a Process handle is held that refers to the current process.
Why is the memory associated with msg "done" not lower than the preceding values?
When the array is nulled and memory reclaimed there is no change in memory footprint either.
On windows 10 I compiled it with csc prog.cs on the command line and when I ran it the following values were shown:

```
priv64=11632640 msg=beginning
priv64=52170752 msg=allocated
priv64=52174848 msg=nulled
priv64=56176640 msg=allocated
priv64=56176640 msg=nulled
priv64=60174336 msg=allocated
priv64=60174336 msg=nulled
priv64=64176128 msg=allocated
priv64=64176128 msg=nulled
priv64=68173824 msg=allocated
priv64=68173824 msg=nulled
priv64=68173824 msg=done
priv64=12173312 msg=exiting
```

Program follows

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime;

class Hmm {
    private static void Reclaim()
    {
        GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    private static void print_mem(Process p, string msg)
    {
        Reclaim();
        p.Refresh();
        Reclaim();
        Console.WriteLine("priv64={0} msg={1}", p.PrivateMemorySize64, msg);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
         using(var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
         {
             print_mem(p, "beginning");
             int size = 10*1000*1000;
             for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
             {
                var a = new int[size+i*1000*1000];
                a[size-1] = 123;
                print_mem(p, "allocated");
                a = null;
                print_mem(p, "nulled");
            }
            // why is PrivateMemorySize64 not decreasing here?
            print_mem(p, "done");
         }

        print_mem(Process.GetCurrentProcess(), "exiting");
    }
};
```

Comment: Memory is *eligible* to be freed once the last reference to it is gone. The garbage collector runs at a non-deterministic time to actually free the memory.

Comment: Is this in a Debug or Release build? Is see no such effect for a Release build.

Comment: Moreover moving the loop out into another method from the "done" call causes the memory to be the same for "done" and "exiting" for me even in a debug build. This suggests it is simply an artifact of how a non-optimized build generates extra temporary variables for debugging purposes.

Comment: program was compiled on the command line with "csc prog.cs" inside a VS2015 64bit cmd prompt. Note that I force a GC.Collect() and wait for the finalizers to finish, collection should be deterministic therefore.

Comment: optimization is tricky because if the optimizer determines that the array is unused in a meaningful way it could eliminate all allocations.